# $\frac{3x^5+1}{x^4+x^3+1}+\frac{3y^5+1}{y^4+y^3+1}+\frac{3z^5+1}{z^4+z^3+1} \ge 4$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove the following inequality $$\frac{3x^5+1}{x^4+x^3+1}+\frac{3y^5+1}{y^4+y^3+1}+\frac{3z^5+1}{z^4+z^3+1} \ge 4$$ where $x,y,z \ge 0$ and $x+y+z=3$

I don't really know how to approach such an inequality. I tried the inequality of means and Cauchy's inequality, but it doesn't seem like I'm getting close to anything. I think that maybe an inequality is being used that I haven't heard of yet.

Edit : I think I managed to prove the inequality, but I'm sure there is a more elegant proof.Here is my take : I will first prove that $\frac{3x^5+1}{x^4+x^3+1} \ge \frac{17}{9}x-\frac{5}{9} \iff \frac{9(3x^5+1)}{9(x^4+x^3+1)}-\frac{17x(x^4+x^3+1)}{9(x^4+x^3+1)} + \frac{5x(x^4+x^3+1)}{9(x^4+x^3+1)} \ge 0 \iff \frac{(x-1)^2(10x^3+8x^2+11x+14)}{9(x^4+x^3+1)} \ge 0$ which is true $\forall x \in [0,\infty)$
So we have that $\frac{3x^5+1}{x^4+x^3+1} \ge \frac{17}{9}x-\frac{5}{9}$ , $\frac{3y^5+1}{y^4+y^3+1} \ge \frac{17}{9}y-\frac{5}{9}$ and $\frac{3z^5+1}{z^4+z^3+1} \ge \frac{17}{9}z-\frac{5}{9}$ . By summing we get that $\frac{3x^5+1}{x^4+x^3+1}+\frac{3y^5+1}{y^4+y^3+1}+\frac{3z^5+1}{z^4+z^3+1} \ge \frac{17}{9}(x+y+z)-\frac{5}{3} = 4$

I'm sure there must be an easier and more elegant method. anyway, I made this solution using an online graph, so I would never have thought of that factorization using pencil and paper.I'm waiting to see what you think about my approach. If you have any idea or a solution, I'm here to listen. Thanks!

Comment: Very good your artifice of  bounding the curve  $\dfrac{3x^5+1}{x^4+x^3+1}$ by a tangent line. I find it as very elegant but I feel this is not suitable in other cases.

Comment: Hi. Can you please elaborate on the motivation to prove $\frac{3x^5+1}{x^4+x^3+1} \ge \frac{17}{9}x-\frac{5}{9}$?. I'm wondering how you got there using the graph of the function

Comment: @IvánGM the tangent line trick is a common tool in contest math, especially if the individual summands are dependent on one variable only. If $f$ is the function, $a$ is the average of the $n$ variables, you want to show $f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)$ holds.

Comment: So frequently they can be solved by assuming the values are all equal. Not sure why it works, but works here too.

Answer (score 2):

*Remark*: Here is an alternative proof via Chebyshev's sum inequality.

We have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{3x^5+1}{x^4+x^3+1} - \frac43
 &= \frac{9x^5 - 4x^4 - 4x^3 - 1}{3(x^4 + x^3 + 1)}\\
  &= \frac{(9x^5 - 9x^4) + (4x^4 - 4x^3) + (x^4 - 1)}{3(x^4 + x^3 + 1)}\\
 &= \frac{9x^4 + 4x^3 + (x+1)(x^2 + 1)}{3(x^4+x^3+1)}\cdot (x-1).
\end{align*}

Since $f(x) := \frac{9x^4 + 4x^3 + (x+1)(x^2 + 1)}{3(x^4+x^3+1)}$ is strictly increasing on $[0, 3]$ (see the Remark at the end), by Chebyshev's sum inequality, we have
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{3x^5+1}{x^4+x^3+1} - 4
\ge \frac13 \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{9x^4 + 4x^3 + (x+1)(x^2 + 1)}{3(x^4+x^3+1)} \cdot (x + y + z - 3) = 0. $$

*Remark*: We have
$$f(x) = 3 + \frac{-4x^3 + x^2 + x - 8}{3x^4 + 3x^3 + 3}.$$
We need to prove that $f'(x) > 0$.
Equivalently, we need to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &\Big(-4x^3 + x^2 + x - 8\Big)'\cdot (x^4+x^3+1)\\
 >{}& \Big(-4x^3 + x^2 + x - 8\Big)\Big((x^4+x^3+1)\Big)'
\end{align*}
or
$$(-12x^2 + 2x + 1)(x^4 + x^3 + 1)
> (-4x^3 + x^2 + x - 8)(4x^3 + 3x^2)$$
or
$$4x^6 - 2x^5 - 4x^4 + 30x^3 + 12x^2 + 2x + 1 > 0$$
which is true (easy by AM-GM, e.g. $3x^6 + 12x^2 \ge 12x^4$, etc).